# Nested matrix with odd alignment

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to get my code to look like this.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,adjustbox}
\begin{document}


\newenvironment{Pbmatrix}[1][c]
 {\begin{adjustbox}{valign=#1}$\begin{bmatrix}}
 {\end{bmatrix}$\end{adjustbox}}

\newcommand{\matt}[5]{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{Pbmatrix}[b]
  2+r_1 & -1  \\
  -1  & 2+r_1 & -1 \\
      & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_1 & -1  \\
      &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_1  \\    
  \end{Pbmatrix} & \begin{Pbmatrix}[b] #3 \end{Pbmatrix} & \\
  \hfill \begin{Pbmatrix}[b] #4 \end{Pbmatrix} & \begin{Pbmatrix}[b] #1 \end{Pbmatrix} & \begin{Pbmatrix}[b] #2 \end{Pbmatrix} \hfill\hfill \\ 
  & \begin{Pbmatrix}[b] #5 \end{Pbmatrix} & \begin{Pbmatrix}[t]
    2+r_2 & -1  \\
    -1  & 2+r_2 & -1 \\
        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
        &        &        &  -1 & 2+r_2 & -1  \\
        &        &        &   & -1 & 2+r_2  \\    
    \end{Pbmatrix}
  \end{bmatrix}
}

\begin{figure}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\displaystyle
\matt {A_1+A_4} {A_2} {-1} {A_3} {-1}
$}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you explain in words what you are trying to do as I don't understand what your picture. Are `[A_3]` and `[A_2]` supposed to be a row vectors and the `[-1]`'s column vectors?

Comment: Andrew .. yes, they are row and column vectors as you described. If you run my code, the [A_2] has the brackets very close against the A_2. I want the outline of that row vector to extend all the way to the right as shown in my picture.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** Given the OPs comment I have rewritten this an simplified it. The single row row vectors and single column column vectors I have put inside `\myRow` and `\myColumn` macros that are just a `bmatrices`. As the size of a `bmatrix` is dependent on its entries it is not enough to make these the same size as the the bigger corner matrices to I have fudged this using `\hspace` and `\vspace` to add horizontal and vertical space, respectively.

[image]

I have first put the two large block matrices into a separate macro to make the code vaguely readable. Next I have dispensed with your use of the [adjustbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) as this just seems to be playing havoc with alignment.

Here's the code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,adjustbox,mathtools}
\begin{document}
%\newcommand\Bigger[2][7]{\left#2\rule{0mm}{#1truemm}\right.}
%\newcommand\pbmatrix[2][18]{\Bigger[#1]{[}#2\Bigger[#1]{]}}
\newcommand\myRow[2]{\bmatrix#1&\hspace*{59.5mm}&#2\endbmatrix}
\newcommand\myColumn[3][18]{\bmatrix#2\\ \vspace*{#1mm}\\ #3\endbmatrix}
\newcommand\myMatrix[1]{\bmatrix%
      2+#1& -1  \\
      -1  & 2+#1 & -1 \\
          & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
          &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
          &        &        &  -1 & 2+#1 & -1  \\
          &        &        &   & -1 & 2+#1  \\
\endbmatrix}

\newcommand{\matt}[5]{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \myMatrix{r_1}& \myColumn{}{#3}&\\
    \myRow{}{#4}  & [#1]           &\myRow{#2}{}\\
                  & \myColumn[23]{#5}{}& \myMatrix{r_2}
  \end{bmatrix}
}

\begin{figure}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\displaystyle
\matt {A_1+A_4} {A_2} {-1} {A_3} {-1}
$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the two column vectors have slightly different vertical adjustments in them. This is done using an optional argument to

```
\myColumn[vertical height]{top entry}{bottom entry}
```

where as the row vector has the same horizontal adjustment. Presumably this is because of the way the `bmatrix` creates the matrix. I found the horizontal and vertical adjustments by trial and error.

Comment: Andrew -- thank you for helping. But I need your picture to look like mine. So the A_3 needs to be right justified in that large row vector. The A_2 needs to be left justified. The top -1 needs to be bottom justified. The bottom -1 needs to be top justified. Otherwise the layout is great!

Comment: Andrew -- I see the problem. My original question was slightly miscommunicated. The A_2 should have the left and right bracket around it EXACTLY as you have drawn it. A_3 should look the same. It should have the left and right bracket also.

Comment: @BobZigon Thanks for the clarification. I've written and simplified the solution based on your comment.